# matching regex in a list of names with Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to extra the characters before the `_` for each `item` in the `list`. What could I be possibly doing wrong?

```py
import re
data_frames = [insuer_df, tax_df, debt_df, death_df, birth_df, will_df]

frames = []
for df in data_frames:
    pattern = re.findall("(w+)\_\[a-z]", str(df))
    frames.append(pattern)
print(frames)
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

My expected output:

```
[insuer, tax, debt, death, birth, will]
```

Comment: I think it is because you are escaping the `\[` and not escaping the `\w` Try `(\w+)_[a-z]`

Comment: Seems you are mixing variable (name)s with strings here.

Comment: It seems like you're expecting `str(df)` to give you the _name_ of the variable in the list, i.e. `"insuer_df"`.  It does not do that.

Comment: True, yes. How do I turn it into a str to match it like a str?

Comment: Declare `data_frames` as a list of strings: `data_frames = ["insuer_df", "tax_df", ...]`

Comment: Also, using a regex here is a bit excessive, you could simply do `pattern = df.split("_")[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whats wrong, but the following code will get you the desired output

```
import re
data_frames = ['insuer_df', 'tax_df', 'debt_df', 'death_df', 'birth_df', 'will_df']

frames = []
for df in data_frames:
    j = df[0:df.find('_')]
    frames.append(j)
print(frames)
```

Keep it simple, any string can be considered as a array, so just find the starting position of `'_'` and extract all before that.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use *match* instead of *findall* and, in the regex, you can create a group with the part of text you need to extract.

With match method, you will receive an object with all groups of texts where:
index 0 - the entire text
index 1 and beyond - text of each group of texts

check the code below:

```
import re
data_frames = ['insuer_df', 'tax_df', 'debt_df', 'death_df', 'birth_df', 'will_df']

frames = []
for df in data_frames:
    j = re.match("([^_]*?)_.*", str(df))
    fragment = j.group(1)
    frames.append(fragment)
print(frames)
```

Best regards,